# Developing Android 9.0 eSIM LPA (system app)

Tags: android

Trying to develop android LPA system app for eSIM with the new Pie [API](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/esim-overview#making_an_lpa_app).

The doc says to extend the abstract EuiccService class. But this class is not in the official SDK, and the link in the docs just leads to corresponding file in the android source repo.

I tried using this file/class as a dependency, but it references other internal android classes/annotations and causes build/IDE errors.

Does anyone have an idea how to use this?

Do I really have to pull android src code and somehow reference required class from it?

<del>**EDIT**: I think I've solved it, found couple of potential solutions, but they were a bit cumbersome. Used the android.jar from here: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api (contains modified android.jar with hidden APIs and internal resources). It didn't work when i replaced the whole file and resulted strange build errors, but i manually transferred the android\service\euicc\ folder to original android.jar of android-28 sdk and it works perfectly (class is available and apk builds without issues). And no need to waste time pulling and building AOSP.</del>

<del>**EDIT #2**: apparently not fully fixable atm. There's issue with android gradle plugins (at least 3.2.x-3.3.x) where during full sync some build task generates mock classes from android.jar and process fails if it's modified (discussion is here: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api/issues/46). Error looks like this:</del>

<del>*Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, returnDefaultValues=false} using transform MockableJarTransform*</del>

<del>There's a workaround for that, though inconvenient:

when you need a full sync for the project, replace the android.jar with original, run sync, restore modified android.jar, the IDE now will run indexing and classes will be available again with build working until next full sync.

Will update this post if/when it's fixed or new solution is found.</del>

EDIT#3: here's probably a final solution for EuiccService case (turned out pretty obvious):
Instead of adding 'android/service/euicc' folder to android.jar, just put it in a separate library and add it as a compileOnly dependency. Since the classes were not in the SDK, the lib should not cause conflict (would be the case if you need to use modified framework or access hidden APIs in already existing classes).

Comment: I had tried to do something similar (before two years) that required Android internal calls and I had to take one-by-one all the files needed from the AOSP. Finally it works but it was painfull. I did'nt find any other way

Comment: Hello, could you explain bit further what you did to so that you got it working? I have already downloaded the aosp code. And I'm currently trying to get this thing working, how did you `import` the library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create a System APP, you will do it in several ways:

- You could call a part of the **SystemAPI** (a method for example) by reference.
- You could make the aplication as a part of the AOSP Project (*Downloading the AOSP code, and introducing your app as part of **packages/apps/***)

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to access system APIs on a rooted device or if you have system permissions (this happens when you flash your app into the device as part of the system image).

However, if you want to be able to call the `EuiccService` class from Android Studio (for coding purposes), you'll need to add the Android framework jar to your project.

The steps are provided below:

1. First, you will have to download and build AOSP and generate a framework jar for your target Android version. Check the documentation [here](https://source.android.com/setup/start) to get an idea of how to download and build AOSP.
2. After a successful build all framework classes are compiled into a jar called `classes.jar` which can be found at the location `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates`.
3. Get this `classes.jar` and add it to your Android project as a jar file.
4. Gradle sync the project and start coding.
5. Please beware that you **WILL NOT BE ABLE TO** run this app on an Adnroid device where you do not have system permission for this app.